# Issue on installing a own written logstash plugin

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, rubygems, logstash, jruby

I am doing my firts steps on writing my own logstash filter plugins. I followed the instructions of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_filter_plugin.html but I do not get it done.

I do this on my windows machine. The following has been ensured

- Proper JAVA_HOME is set and its bin folder is added to PATH
- JRuby is installed
- Proper JRUBY_HOME is set and its bin folder is added to PATH

I did the following

1. Cloned and did NO source code changes on https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-example.git
2. Did a successful gem build which created the file logstash-filter-example-3.0.0.gem
3. Wanted to see if the plugin is working and tried to install it

Got this error message

```
logstash-plugin.bat install logstash-filter-example-3.0.0.gem
LoadError: no such file to load -- clamp
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956
  require at C:/jruby-9.1.5.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
   <main> at D:\hust\playground\logstash_filter_plugin\logstash-2.4.0\logstash-2.4.0\lib\pluginmanager\main.rb:14
```

I am a newbie to this world. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

BW Hubert

Comment: is your gem file in the same folder as `logstash-plugin.bat`? If not, then you need to provide the full path to your gem

Comment: yes it is in the same folder